# Error 401 api woocommerce when trying to do GET (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, woocommerce

I'm doing a project with Reactjs, which consumes data from wordpress and Woocommerce. The Worpress data extracts them correctly but the Woocommerce data returns a 401 error.

The first thing I thought was an error in the keys of the client or the secret but they are correct and created another new one in case they were failing but it remains the same.

I also want to add that when I worked in local (localhost) everything worked correctly, but as I have changed to an external server which has its respective wordpress and woocommerce.

```
const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://www.xxxxxx.xxxxx.com/',
  consumerKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  consumerSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  wpAPI: true,
  version: 'wc/v3',
  queryStringAuth: true
 });

 WooCommerce.getAsync('customers').then((result) => {
  let customers = JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);

  this.setState({
    customers: customers,
  });
```

> ERROR: {code: "woocommerce_rest_authentication_error", message: "La
>   clave de cliente > no es válida.", data: {…}} code:
>   "woocommerce_rest_authentication_error" data: {status: 401} message:
>   "La clave de cliente no es válida." proto: Object

Comment: Try to use `"http://www.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/wp-json/wp/v3/users"` instead of `"http://www.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users"`. Version number is causing authentication issue. Another issue is check consumer key and secret key. Are they exists in a Woocommerce API section?

Comment: One more thinf, please follow this documentation for Woocommerce API call: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html#introduction

Comment: I've tried with version 3 and in the documentation I can not find anything to help me.